# Группировка элементов li внутри ul

Tags: html, css

У меня такая проблема.
Есть структура на странице
упрощенно:

```
<ul class="example">
        <li class="first">Быстрый выбор:</li>

            <li><a href="#" id="1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="4">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="5">5</a></li>

        <li class="second">
            <a> some some some some some </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

стили css не привести т.к. их ну очень много.

на странице все отображается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда я уменьшаю масштаб some съезжает вниз а потом выравнивается под верхним предложением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно чтобы он сразу выравнивался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот так](https://jsfiddle.net/1drf9syg/), например

```
.example {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

li:nth-last-child(2) {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Но, на самом деле, разумнее было бы заверстать отдельными списками.

Comment: спасибо, проверил но some при сдвиге экрана опускает вниз под список)

Comment: @Padawan, обновил)